# Biggest diameter of a set with a distance function

Tags: algorithm, distance, theory

I have a set of elements with a distance function between elements satisfying the triangle inequality.

I want to find the pair of elements separated by the greatest distance.

Is there any known solution better than trying all pairs?

Comment: can your elements be ordered?

Comment: This sounds like a variation on the "closest pair of points problem", which can be solved in O(n log n) if the elements are points in 2-D space and you have access to the individual coordinates of the points.

Comment: I note that if there are N dimensions you need distances from N known points to fix a position in space, so if you know where N of N+1 points are and you know only N-1 of the distances to the N+1th point you cannot compute the Nth distance. So I would be surprised to find an algorithm for closest pair of points on N+1 points in N dimensions that did not compute the distances between all the pairs.

Comment: @mcdowella You don't need to know the location of the points; in fact you don't even need to know how many dimensions the space has. You only need to know that the distance between a pair of points is shorter than the distance between another pair of points to disqualify the first pair of points from being the furthest apart. If you measure the distance between some of the pairs, and use the triangle inequality to deduce that the distances between the rest of the pairs is smaller than the maximum distance found, you have your answer without measuring every pair.

Comment: @m69 You don't need to know the number of dimensions but if your points are randomly scattered through a space of N dimensions then as N gets larger and larger the inequalities get less and less useful. Consider random bit-vectors of length N. Two such vectors are different in an average of N/2 places with a standard deviation of sqrt(3N)/2. So for large N almost all of the pairwise distances are close enough together, comparatively speaking, that it is very unlikely that |ab| + |ac| < |ad|. This is why clever spatial indexing schemes have trouble as the number of dimensions increases.

Comment: @mcdowella I don't quite follow the "different in an average of N/2 places" bit; do you perhaps have a link to the theory behind this? (I'll experiment with random data in more dimensions tomorrow to check the effect in practice.)

Comment: Compare two random bits. They are different with probability 1/2 (01 or 10 as opposed to 00 or 11). With bit-vectors of length N you are comparing N bits, and the probabilities follow from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution. For much more see e.g. https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~venkatg/teaching/CStheory-infoage/chap1-high-dim-space.pdf "Then increase the dimension and generate the points uniformly
at random in a 100-dimensional unit cube. The distribution of distances becomes
concentrated about an average distance. The reason is easy to see....."

Comment: @mcdowella Thanks.

Comment: @mcdowella I added some test results for multi-dimensional spaces.

Comment: @m69 interesting - thanks. Yes, even if the data appears to be in a high dimensional space there is always the hope that there is some sort of correlation that means that it is only really occupying a smaller dimensional subspace and this sort of thing will pay off.

Answer (score 3):

If you measure the distance from point a to points b, c and d, and you find that  |ab| + |ac| < |ad|, then you know that |bc| is shorter than |ad|, and there's no need to measure |bc|. So not all pairs need to be checked to find the longest distance.

A possible algorithm would be:
Start by measuring the distance from point a to all other points, find the point n which is furthest away from a, and then give all pairs b,x for which |ab|+|ax| < |an| the distance |ab|+|ax| (because that is their maximum possible distance).
Do the same for point b, measuring only those distances which haven't yet been set. Check if you've found a new maximum, and then again give all pairs c,x for which |bc|+|bx| < MAX the distance |bc|+|bx|.
Go on doing this for points c, d, ...

In the best case scenario, you could find the longest distance in a set of N points after just N-1 measurements (if |ax| is twice as long as any other distance from a). In the worst case, you would need to measure every single pair (if the shortest distance is more than half of the longest distance, or if you are unlucky in the order in which you run through the points).

---

If you want to reduce the number of distance measurements to the absolute minimum, and for every unknown distance x,y you check every previously stored value |ax|+|ay|, |bx|+|by|, |cx|+|cy| ... to see whether it's smaller than the current maximum and can thus be used as a value for |xy|, the number of measurements is reduced substantially.

Running this algorithm on 1000 random points in a square 2D space, which would normally require 499,500 measurements, returns the maximum distance with between 2,000 and 10,000 measurements (or between 0.4% and 2% of the total, with an average around 1%).

This doesn't necessarily mean that the algorithm is much faster in practice than measuring every distance; that depends on how expensive the measuring is compared to the combination of loops, additions and comparisons required to avoid the measurements.

---

As @mcdowella pointed out, this method becomes less efficient as the number of dimensions of the space increases. The number of points also has a big impact. The table below shows the number of measurements that have to be carried out in relation to the total number of pairs. These are averages from a test with randomly distributed points in a "square" space (i.e. the coordinates in all dimensions are within the same range). As you can see, this method makes most sense for geometrical problems with many points in a 2D or 3D space. However, if your data is highly biased in some way, the results may be different.

```
       10 points (45 pairs)      100 points (4950 pairs)   1000 points (499500 pairs)
dim    measurem.   % of total    measurem.   % of total    measurem.   % of total

 1      16.6674      37.04         221.17       4.47        4877.97       0.98
 2      22.4645      49.92         346.77       7.01        5346.78       1.07
 3      27.5892      61.31         525.73      10.62        7437.16       1.49
 4      31.9398      70.98         731.83      14.78       12780.02       2.56
 5      35.3313      78.51         989.27      19.99       19457.84       3.90
 6      38.1420      84.76        1260.89      25.47       26360.16       5.28
 7      40.2296      89.40        1565.80      31.63       33221.32       6.65
 8      41.6864      92.64        1859.08      37.56       44073.42       8.82
 9      42.7149      94.92        2168.03      43.80       56374.36      11.29
10      43.4463      96.55        2490.69      50.32       73053.06      14.63
20      44.9789      99.95        4617.41      93.28      289978.20      58.05
30      44.9996      99.999       4936.68      99.73      460056.04      92.10
40                                4949.79      99.99      496893.10      99.48
50                                4949.99      99.9999    499285.80      99.96
60                                                        499499.60      99.9999
```

As expected, the results of the tests become predictable at higher dimensions, with only a few percent between the outliers, while in 2D some test cases required 30 times more measurements than others.